# Tensor product of matrices

Tags: tensor-products, kronecker-product

Generally when people talk about tensor product of matrices, is it safe to assume they are referring to Kronecker product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, generally.  But it would be polite of them to have said so, and not impolite of you to ask.

Comment: Ok great, many thanks.